# ConfigError: field "properties" not yet prepared so type is still a ForwardRef, you might need to call APIRequestBodyProperty.update_forward_refs()

Tags: yaml, openapi, pydantic, langchain

I am following the instructions in this tutorial - https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/apis/openapi#example-post-message  for my api.
My api looks like this -

```
https://someurl/api/get-fruits?start_letter=a

Response - 
{fruit_list:[
     {
    name: "apple",
    fruit_color: ['red','green','pink'],
    seasonal: True,
    imported_from: [['Maryland'],['California']]
    }
    ]}
```

And my yaml file looks like this -

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: fruits and vegetables
  description: description of fruits and vegetables
  version: 'v1'
servers:
  - url: https://someurl
paths:
  /api/get-fruits:
    post:
      requestBody:
        required: True
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/fruitRequest'
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  fruit_list:
                    type: array
                    items:
                      $ref: '#/components/schemas/fruitResponse'

components:
  schemas:
    fruitRequest:
      type: object
      properties:
        start_letter:
          type: string
          description: fruit starts with letter provided by user.
    fruitResponse:
      type: object
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
          description: fruit name.
        fruit_color:
          type: array
          items: 
            type: array
            items:
              type: string
          description: List of colors.
        seasonal:
          type: boolean
          description: Whether its seasonal
        imported_from:
          type: array
          items:
            type: array
            items:
              type: string
          description: List of countries its imported from.
```

This is a valid yaml file.
But when I do the first step of reading the spec yaml file, I get the error -

```
spec = OpenAPISpec.from_file("fruits.yaml")


ConfigError: field "properties" not yet prepared so type is still a ForwardRef, you might need to call APIRequestBodyProperty.update_forward_refs().
```

If I do

```
spec = spec.update_forward_refs()
```

the error disappears but spec becomes NoneType and I get an error in next step of operation.

**EDIT** - I have updated the yaml. It is a valid yaml now.

Comment: Did you write the OpenAPI file manually or generate it from code? It's not a valid OpenAPI file, as you can see if you paste it into https://editor.swagger.io. Some of the errors: 1) Under `components/schemas`, the `fruitResponse:` line must have the same indentation level as `fruitRequest:` 2) `type: List[List[str]]` is not a valid type, the property should be defined as an [array](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#array) of strings instead.

Comment: @Helen Thank you. I created it manually, by checking the example yaml - https://api.speak.com/openapi.yaml   Thanks for the swagger editor link. The mistakes you pointed are valid and will fix it.  But when I paste the yaml from the link example I shared, there are a bunch of errors in it too, but I don't get the config error.

Comment: @Helen I tried the same with a valid yaml and got the same error.

Comment: Might be a bug in Langchain. Maybe someone else knows.